# Why is chrome_debug.log generated only if chrome launches by shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I am trying to enable Google Chrome browser debug logs in order to consult the output file generated (chrome_debug.log).

Problem is that everythig i tried so far resulted in creating the log file only if google chrome was launched by shortcut.

Is there a way to enable chrome debug logs everytime an instance of chrome launches and not only by shortcut?

So far, i tried following the official google guide at:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en
this works only by shortcut